# What is the origin of fried potato?

Tags: potatoes, deep-frying

What is the origin of fried potato? Is it France that introduced it through French fries to the world?

EDIT: By origin I mean the first most popular amongst the world.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a culinary question here - this seems more about history, which although interesting is bordering on off-topic and outside the area of expertise for users here.

Comment: I think this question is unanswerable. The real origin (in which country was the first potato in the world fried) is certainly not documented, it probably predates writing. As for current popularity, there is no single measure, and if it were, nobody can do the statistics, because nobody is going to homes and restaurants to document whether they fry, boil or bake the potatoes they buy.

Comment: @rumtscho Would appreciate your insight on this in meta: http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1921/are-questions-about-the-history-of-foods-and-cooking-off-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opinion is divided (usually along the border) as to whether the French or the Belgians invented French fries. The name favours the former, but this is possibly due to the fact that the French are seen as having invented gastronomy in general.

It is probably impossible to answer - who knows when the first adventurous cook decided to try frying potato alongside his piece of fish?